# Buying a house from a trust that you own

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates

Suppose that person X is the beneficiary and the sole trustee of an irrevocable asset protection trust. He is not the grantor of the trust. The trust has stocks, bonds and an house in it. Person X has the right to take assets from the trust. That is, if he wanted to he could just transfer the house to himself. Can person X buy the house from the trust at fair market value?

Comment: If the person _can_ "just transfer the house to himself", but is considering buying it at FMV, is there some downside to the transfer that they are trying to avoid?

Comment: While these questions are on topic, if they are not just hypothetical then you would be better posting them on money.stackexchange. They can and do give advice for specific situations.

Comment: If person X has the right to take assets from the trust it isn't an asset protection trust in any meaningful sense.

Comment: The idea of buying the house is to put more money into  the trust.

Comment: @ohwilleke My post left out this detail.  The beneficiary can only take money out  with  permission from the  trustee even though they are the same person. That is suppose to give it asset protection. Are you still saying that the trust does not provide meaningful asset protection?

Comment: @Bob I am saying that this does not provide very strong asset protection. It isn't absolutely zero, but you would never call such a trust an "asset protection trust". A HEMS standard (health, education, maintenance, and support) can provide slight protection, but not very much. Absent ascertainable standards, it provides zero asset protection. A general power of appointment over trust assets (unlimited right to withdraw assets for yourself, your creditors, your estate, or the creditors of your estate) is equivalent to outright ownership and provides no protection at all.

Answer (score 3):

The primary question is why the trustee is disposing of the asset at all. The trustee has a particular fiduciary duty (we haven't seen the document so we have no idea what that duty is). It could be justified because, for example, the grantor needs cash for a brain operation. Self-dealing (acting in one's own interest, which is a conflict of interest), is prohibited for a trustee. With real estate, "fair market value" is a fluid concept, but within limits one can determine that a sale (to self) at $900,000 undervalued the house and that a sale to another would have garnered $1,100,000, therefore this would be an illegal self-dealing. However, the simple act of a trustees purchasing an asset from a trust that he is the trustee of is not categorially prohibited.

Comment: I would assume if the assets are to be disposed of it would not really matter who buys, unless there is specifics on who should buy it. But a dollar is a dollar regardless of the source.